# Why do we talk about inertia tensor?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, tensor-calculus, rigid-body-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

When we talk about the inertia of a rigid body, in calculating the angular momentum as a function of the moment of inertia and angular velocity, the inertia tensor is introduced. But why is it a tensor?

The moment of inertia is defined as $$I=\int_V \! r^2 \, \mathrm{d}m.$$ where $r^2$ is the squared distance of the $dV$ from the axis of rotation and $m$ is the mass, why is $I$ a tensor?

According to "Manifolds, Tensor Analysis and Applications - Marsden, Ratiu and Abraham" a tensor over a Banach space $E$ is a multilinear map defined on the cartesian product of $r$ dual space $E*$ and $p$ space $E$ which takes values on $\mathbb{R}$. I can't see this definition on $I$.

$I$ seems to me a linear functional from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^+$ because it takes a function $r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$ and gives out a scalar.

**The question is:**

Why we talk about a tensor of inertia and not a linear operator of inertia or a linear functional of inertia?

Comment: Don't have time at the moment to write up an answer but: [Moment of inertia](https://web.chem.ox.ac.uk/teaching/Physics%20for%20CHemists/Rotation/Moment%20of%20inertia.html) and [Moment of Inertia Tensor](https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newton/node64.html)

Comment: Does the answer given in [Understanding and Expressing the Definition of Inertia Tensor in the Language of Differential Geometry](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/538448/203278) answer your question?

Comment: Note also that Abraham and Marsden have a massive text on classical mechanics, which you might be interested in glossing through (it's a little rough going). A much more readable text I found is Curtis and Miller's [*Differential Manifolds and Theoretical Physics*](https://books.google.ca/books/about/Differential_Manifolds_and_Theoretical_P.html?id=euzNPgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y). There is a chapter on rigid body motion, which you may be interested in.

Comment: @peek-a-boo The answer given in that post is way too difficult for me, I just understand that the Inertia tensor is a $(0,2)$ tensor, so a map which takes two vectors and gives a scalar, but can't understand what vectors it takes.

Comment: You can imagine it just takes two vectors in $E=\Bbb{R}^3$ and produces a number according to a certain integral formula.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Ok about that but the two vectors are, for example $x^2$ and $y^2$ or the density $\rho$?

Comment: Neither. For example in the $I_{zz}$ term it eats the vectors $e_3=(0, 0,1)$ twice.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Ok I understand, only one thing, why twice? in $I_{zz}$ there is $(x^2+y^2)$ so why twice? Beacuse $x^2+y^2=z\cdot z$?

Comment: $I(v,w)=\int_B(r^2\langle v,w\rangle - \langle \vec{r},v\rangle \langle \vec{r},w\rangle)\,dm$. That's the definition of the inertia tensor with respect to coordinates $\vec{r}=(x,y,z)$ about the center of mass. Here, $v,w\in\Bbb{R}^3$. THis takes two vectors and outputs a number, and clearly it is bilinear. $I_{zz}$ is by definition $I_{33}=I(e_3,e_3)=\int_B(r^2\langle e_3,e_3\rangle -\langle\vec{r},e_3\rangle\langle\vec{r},e_3\rangle)\,dm=\int_B(r^2-z^2)\,dm=\int_B(x^2+y^2)\,dm$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137224/discussion-between-peek-a-boo-and-salmone).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you, it's almost all clear, by $r^2\langle v,w\rangle$ you mean $r^2$ times $\langle v,w\rangle$? Where $\langle v,w\rangle$ is the dot product?

Comment: yes (___ filling blank space ___)

Comment: @peek-a-boo I have another little question, since we are calculating the moment of inertia with respect to the center of mass, are we assuming the rigid body is rotating on itself? Otherwise, if it were rotating about another axis system, the calculated moment of inertia with respect to the center of mass would be zero.

Answer (score 13):

A rank 2 tensor is something that relates two vectors. In this case, the MMOI tensor relates the rotational velocity vector to the angular momentum vector.

Given a solid whose internal particles are designated with $\vec{r}$ in relation to the center of mass, you have the following volume integral to find the angular momentum of the body.
$$ \vec{L} = \int \vec{r} \times (\vec{v}\, {\rm d}m) = \int  \vec{r} \times (\vec{v} \rho \,{\rm d} V). $$
Here $\vec{v} = \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}$ is the motion of each particle, so
$$ \vec{L} = \int  [\vec{r} \times  ( \vec{\omega} \times \vec{r})] \rho\, {\rm d} V.$$
With the vector identity $\vec{a}\times ( \vec{b} \times \vec{c}) = \vec{b} ( \vec{a} \cdot \vec{c}) - \vec{c} ( \vec{a}\cdot \vec{b}) = ( \vec{a}\cdot \vec{c}) \vec{b} - (\vec{c} \odot \vec{a}) \vec{b} $, where $\cdot$ is the inner (dot) product, and $\odot$ is the outer product,
$$ \vec{L}=  \int  \left(  \vec{r} \cdot \vec{r} - \vec{r} \odot \vec{r} \right) \vec{\omega}\, \rho\,{\rm d} V.$$
And the integral is factored by the mass moment of inertia tensor
$$ \vec{L} = \mathrm{I}\, \vec{\omega} $$
$$ \mathrm{I} \equiv \int  \left(  \vec{r} \cdot \vec{r} - \vec{r} \odot \vec{r} \right)  \rho\, {\rm d} V.$$

---

If $\vec{r} = \pmatrix{x \\y \\ z}$ then the integral is
$$ \mathrm{I} \equiv \int  \begin{bmatrix} y^2+z^2 & -x y & -x z \\ -x y & x^2+z^2 & - y z \\ -x z & - y z & x^2+y^2 \end{bmatrix}  \rho\, {\rm d} V, $$
from which you are familiar with the 2D version
$$ \mathrm{I}_{zz} \equiv \int  (x^2+y^2)  \rho\, {\rm d} V.$$

Comment: @mr_e_man - yeah I fixed the outer product. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand so much your firt sentence, "A rank 2 tensor is something that relates two vectors", so why don't we talk for example of an **operator of inertia** to which a matrix can be associated anyway?

Comment: I just stating the [definition of a tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#Definition). And [for reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/412454/3301) read answers on mathematics. A tensor maps vectors into vectors, or said otherwise, is a relationship (a 1:1 mapping in reality) between vectors.

Comment: For example in the definition $\mathrm{I}_{\rm zz} \equiv \int  (x^2+y^2)  \rho {\rm d} V$, what are the two vectors the tensor "takes"?

Comment: @Salmone - ${\rm I}_{\rm zz}$ is just a single component of the MMOI tensor. This scalar value can itself be considered a rank 0 tensor, relating rotational speed along the _z_-axis to angular momentum along the _z_-axis.

Answer (score 10):

The moment of inertia you mentioned is only for a single, given axis of rotation. It's used to compute the angular momentum related to his axis:

$$L=I\omega$$

If you want to generalize the result in 3D space to compute the *vector* angular momentum as a function of the rotation *vector*, then:

$$\vec{L}=I\vec{\omega}$$

$I$ needs to become a $3\times 3$ matrix, which is called the inertia tensor.

If the rotation happens around a single axis $z$, you can choose a basis where one of the base vectors is alongisde this axis. Then the expression simplifies to:

$$L_z
=\vec{L}.\vec{e}_z=
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b & c\\
e & f & g\\
i & j & k
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
\omega
\end{pmatrix}.\vec{e}_z
=k\omega$$

which is "single axis" result that you mentioned.

The basis in which $I$ is diagonal defines a specific set of axes that is sometimes useful is study the dynamics of the solid. In this basis, the (scalar) definition of $I$ that you gave can be used for each axis to compute three moments of inertie that are the eigenvalues of $I$.

Comment: I understood the part about the 3D speech but I still can't understand why $I$ is a tensor. $I$ could be represented by a $3x3$ matrix but why is it a tensor? Couldn't it be just a linear functional?

Comment: While there is a mathematical difference between a matrix and a tensor, in this context it matters very little. In physics, the difference is mostly in the behavior with relation to rotations: roughly speaking, the tensor must transform properly under the rotation to keep the same physical meaning before and after (see passive and active transformations in group theory).

Comment: No I don't understand. Is it possible to know what mathematical object $I$ is? Is it a function or a linear map or a linear operator or I don't know what?

Comment: You'll probably want to open a new question for that. In a nutshell, mathematically it's a multilinear map. But in physics we add an additional constraint, in that it must behave in a certain way under rotations, i.e. be part of a representation of the group of rotations in $\mathbb{R}^3$. It's important so that we can write formulas that don't depend on the choice of coordinates.

Comment: I'll open a new question for that but I have a new question about what you wrote in the first answer: if we have a body rotating only around axis z, the terms of the inertia tensor $I_{xx}=\int_V \! z^2+y^2) \, \mathrm{d}m.$ and $I_{yy}=\int_V \! (x^2+z^2) \, \mathrm{d}m.$ that represents the moment of inertia with respect to $x$ and $y$ axis, are equal to zero?

Comment: They can be non zero, they simply vanish from the equation because the rotation vector only has non-zero component on $z$, and because angular momentum is projected on $z$. See my answer, all tensor elements except $k$ vanish from the result without having to be zero.

Comment: Yes I saw you answer, I was just wondering if the elements on the diagonal must vanish or not but the answer is not since the distance of an element of the body from the axis is different from zero at least in some point.

Comment: The very definition of the moment of inertia prevents it from being zero. It means that all three eigenvalues of the inertia tensors (the three moments of inertia) are strictly positive.

Comment: This makes sense to me.